# Closing Material UI menu causes an open dialog to be closed

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a Material UI menu and a dialog in a complex application.

They have no relation to each other whatsover. They are not children of each other. They do not import anything from each other.

The menu sets a state in a context (basically like event-driven programming) and the dialog is shown or closed based on the value of that state.

So basically the `onClick` of a `MenuItem` is like this:

```
onClick={(e) => {
    setRequestedItem('Edition') // this causes the dialog to open
    setAnchorEl(null) // this causes the menu to close
}}
```

But the point is, by calling the `setAnchorEl(null)` the dialog is also closed immediately after the menu is closed.

It's as if Material UI internally uses the same backdrop and modal component for everything and mixes states together.

How can I debug and fix this?

Comment: Do you  open the dialog after opening the menu?

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I'm facing the same issue.